# Elasticsearch id field is empty using Nest IndexMany with Bulk indexing

Tags: asp.net, elasticsearch, nest

Somehow, my object's id field is not being stored, but all other fields are?

The code:

```
// Assuming a list of Products
var products = // entity framework code to get a list of products
var node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node);
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
var descriptor = new BulkDescriptor();    
descriptor.IndexMany(products, (bd, q) => bd.Id(q.id).Index("products"));
client.Bulk(descriptor);
```

The sample product class I'm using:

```
public class Product
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string nameEn { get; set; }
    public string nameFr { get; set; }
}
```

Result as shown in Kabana:

```
id: nameEn: nameFr: _id:C _type:productsearch _index:products _score:1
```

Note how the `id` field is empty, but the Elasticsearch `_id` field is defined correctly.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: How is `products` populated? Are values assigned to the `id` properties of `Product` types within the collection?

Comment: `products` are populated via an entity framework query and ids are assigned. If I change the name of the `id` property to something else, that works.

Comment: What does the request to Elasticsearch look like? You can get this a few different ways: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/logging.html